# Measure theory (Singularity)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, singular-measures

If $μ$ and $v$ be positive measures on $(X,Σ)$ such that each positive $ϵ$ there is a set $A$ in $Σ$ that satisfies $μ(A)<ϵ$ and $ν(A^c)<ϵ$. Now how to prove that $μ$ and $v$ are mutually singular? As far as I understand that I have to choose sets $A_1, A_2, ...$ in such a way that $A=∩ ∪ A_k$, but I can't figure out how to choose $A_k$, please help.

Comment: I took the liberty of replacing $μ(A^c)$ by $ν(A^c)$, as otherwise the question makes no sense. If I was wrong, please edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Start out by taking $A_k$ satisfying $μ(A_k)<2^{-k}$ and $ν(A_k^c)<2^{-k}$, then put $B_n=\bigcup_{k=n}^∞ A_k$. You should find (using countable subadditivity) that $μ(B_n)<2^{1-n}$, while $ν(B_n^c)=0$ (since $B_n^c⊆A_k^c$ for all $k≥n$). Now take $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty B_n$.

Comment: I am confused with your hint. Can you please tell me in detail? Because I thought I have to find a sequence of Ak.

Comment: Well, my thinking was that now you have a $B$ for every $ε>0$, form another sequence of $B$s to get what you want. But now I see that the sequence I started with will do the job just fine, with just a bit of tweaking. I'll update my answer, but I don't have the time to do much details. Should've been in bed two hours ago … (Done. Final remark: You don't *have* to use this method, but it is quite useful, as you can see.)